# IIS Express: How to accept connections from the local network?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2107 + IIS Express.

I need to test a Xamarin app connecting to my ASP Net Core WebAPI.

**How to configure the ASP Net project  + IIS Express to accept connections * from the network, not only localhost ?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43135040/194717